# How to reference a object method in another object method

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a basic lack in understanding the OOP for javascript. What I understand is that I can make classes like this

```
var Car = function(){}

Car.prototype.GetBrand = function(){ return "Ford";}
Car.prototype.GetYear = function(){ return "1989";}

var ford = new Car();

ford.GetBrand();
ford.GetYear();
```

this works...
Now I want to implement a function GetInfo and this should print out Brand & Date

how can I reference the GetBrand() and GetYear() methods in my GetInfo() method.

```
  This is not working:
Car.prototype.GetInfo = function(){ 
        return this.GetBrand()+ ' '+ this.GetYear();
    }
```

this is not the right accessor... 
What do I miss here?

OK edit:
this was a simplified example there my realy method call is in anothe function and that's why we are talking about another scope:

```
JsonLoader.prototype.GetJsonAndMerge = function(url,template,tagToAppend){
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        this.ShowItems(data,template,tagToAppend); 
        }
    });
}
```

I try to reach my ShowItems method... here and this is again in a function that's maybe why the this operator does not work... sorry for the confusion =/

Comment: well what is your ShowItems method actually part of? and why are you trying to reach it with `this`?

Comment: Wowzers. That's a completely different issue. A good lesson in why you should test your reduced test cases to make sure they still show the same problem (with the same error messages).

Comment: @Thomas Shields: ShowItems is also (or should be) a member method of JsonLoader,... JsonLoader.prototype.ShowItems(data, template, tagToAppend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an unintended recursion:

```
Car.prototype.GetInfo = function (){  
  return this.GetBrand()+ ' '+ this.GetYear(); // instead of GetInfo() !
}
```

Then you can call

```
ford.GetInfo() // returns "Ford 1989"
```

---

EDIT: The reason to use `prototype` here is to conserve memory. When you call `new Car()`, the object gets copied, not "constructed" in the traditional sense. Calling `new` on

```
var Car = function(){
  this.GetBrand = function(){ return "Ford";}
  this.GetYear = function(){ return "1989";}
}
```

would also copy the function bodies to every instance. This is why putting a method into the prototype chain makes sense. Also adding a function to already-existing instances only works when adding it to the prototype chain.

Also note that the convention is to give capital first letters to constructor functions only, so `Car` is okay, but `GetInfo` *should* be `getInfo`.

---

```
JsonLoader.prototype.GetJsonAndMerge = function(url,template,tagToAppend){
  var self = this;
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      self.ShowItems(data,template,tagToAppend); 
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I might have another scope issue... I edited the question. I was hitting submit to early...

Comment: @serverinfo: Yes, see my second edit. The meaning of `this` changes from context to context. If you want to preserve a certain meaning across calls, you must store the current `this` in a temporary variable.

Comment: @serverinfo: Never mind! :) Explanation: When the Ajax success callback is invoked, it is done without any context. `this` is always the object a function is *invoked on* (this is why `function.call()` and `function.apply()` can work in the first place) - and the callback function is invoked on no particular object. Hence, `this` is the global (`window`) object for the callback, which does not know about `ShowItems()`. The contents of `self` (and that of the arguments) is preserved through the closure that you create here.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling GetInfo from inside its definition; naturally that's not going to work:

```
Car.prototype.GetInfo = function(){ 
        return this.GetBrand()+ ' '+ this.GetInfo(); //note GetInfo here
    }
```

I believe you want:

```
Car.prototype.GetInfo = function(){ 
            return this.GetBrand()+ ' '+ this.GetYear(); //note GetYear here
        }
```

...then just call it with `ford.GetInfo()`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `GetInfo` recursively.

You probably mean:

```
return this.GetBrand()+ ' '+ this.GetYear();
//                                   ^^^^
```

Which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is context sensitive to how the function it is in is called.

You are trying to use `this` from when `foo.GetJsonAndMerge` is called, but you aren't using it in `GetJsonAndMerge`. You are using it in an anonymous function which is called by `$.ajax`.

You need to make a copy of the current value of `this` in a variable that will remain available to the anonymous function when it gets called.

```
JsonLoader.prototype.GetJsonAndMerge = function(url,template,tagToAppend){
    var that = this; // COPY THIS
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // USE THE COPY YOU PLACED IN THAT INSTEAD OF THIS
            that.ShowItems(data,template,tagToAppend); 
        }
    });
}
```